# Query Hangs

Tags: c#, oracle

Ok, this seems simple but I can't find a solution to save my life. I am trying to do a very simple INSERT query on an Oracle DB. I can log into the DB in TOAD with the same credentials as I use in the code and run the INSERT with no problem, so as near as I can tell there are no permissions issues with the credentials and the query itself is syntacticly correct. When I try to run the below code, it just hangs. No errors or anything. I can see the session pop up in TOAD so as far as I can tell the code establishes the connection with no problem. Here is the code:

```
        String connStr = "Data Source=DB;User id=<USER>;Password=<PASSWORD>;";
        String query = "INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES (values)";

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
```

I have also tried using an ADO connection and got the same result. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: is the new row in the database even when it hangs?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. It is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you committed or rolled back the transaction in Toad?  Your application could be waiting on a lock held by your session created by Toad.

Comment: I have not but I will try that now.

Comment: Ding! Ding! Ding! We have a winner! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice, I was waiting to hear if the row was in the DB to mention this.

Comment: I've been burned by this more times then I can count.  The worst is starting a batch job, forgetting to commit the transaction in SQL-Developer (or Toad in this example), and coming back in an hour to see that no progress has been made.

Comment: Classic case of me knowing just enough about something to get myself into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping it in a transaction and explicitly committing after the insert? IIRC, Oracle's default semantics are very transaction-oriented, unlike SQL Server's.

Comment: I will try this. If you have code that would help. Regardless I'll poke around the web and see if I can find an example.